# JS Two Decimal Places .toFixed(2)

Tags: javascript

.toFixed is not working in my code. I am using it with `.toLocaleString()`

JS / Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8b6t90f5/

```js
$(function() {
  var value = 5000.3269588;


  $("#process").click(function() {

    $('#amount').text("Total: $" + value.toLocaleString().toFixed(2));

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="amount"></div>

<input id="process" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="SHOW VALUE">
```

Comment: Use `toFixed` on the number, not the string

Comment: `I am using it with .toLocaleString()`
That is why it is not working.

Comment: @NickA because it's a different question?

Comment: @NickA - His previous question involved the correct number to use as an argument to `.toFixed()`.  This one invloves an error he saw when chaining `.toLocaleString()` with `toFixed()`.

Comment: @BadZen Sure, but if OP was already aware that using `toFixed` worked when used on a number, why would using `toLocaleString` *before* `toFixed` be the first thing that came to mind, the question is essentially asking how to use `toFixed`, the solution, on a number

Comment: You'd have to ask him.   But it's still a different question.

Comment: @BadZen Yes, it is

Answer (score 1):

Strings do not have a `toFixed()`, only numbers do.

```
      $('#amount').text("Total: " + value.toLocaleString("en-US", {maximumFractionDigits:2, currency:"USD", style:"currency"}));
```

is possibly what you're after.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. now `.toLocaleString()` is not working.

Comment: It should show 5000.33 as 5,000.33 with thousand separator

Comment: Why the downvote, guy who just replayed my previous answer?

Comment: @YOU - Now I see what you are looking for.   Edited my answer, try that.

Answer (score 0):

`toFixed()` is a `Number` method. `toLocaleString()` turns it into a string. You need to use `toFixed()` first, then parse that back to float and use `toLocaleString()`:

```
parseFloat(value.toFixed(2)).toLocalString('en-BR');
```

```js
const num = 50023.357289357;
console.log(parseFloat(num.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString());
```

Comment: `toLocaleString()` isn't working in your code above.

Comment: .toFixed() returns a string. You could try replacing the second line with `console.log(parseFloat(num.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString()));`

Comment: Indeed. Adding `parseFloat()` will fix it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Strings and indeed all objects have `.toLocaleString()`.

Comment: This answer does not give the correct locale-specific representation of the currency value; you need to add the currency symbol by hand in a one-for-all-locales way.  And parseFloat() returns the value as Number, making the toLocaleString() pointless.  And it can also break if parseFloat does not handle the locale's numeric representation, which is absolutely the case for some locales.

Comment: My short snippet had a `)` in the wrong place. The `toLocaleString()` should have come after it. And yes, you do need to add the currency symbol, but the question wasn't strictly about the currency symbol. If you supply the values to get the currency symbol to show up, you are effectively hard-coding which locale it'll use anyways, so you might as well just concat the symbol and keep it a bit simpler.

Answer (score -1):

You continue to use string methods for numbers and vice versa. Try this:

```js
const num = 5000.3269588;
console.log(num.toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumFractionDigits: 2}));
```

Comment: Where did that `num` value come from?

Comment: There's a current browser inconsistency bug using `undefined` as the first argument.   You should try to avoid that.

Comment: (also OP is trying to format a currency in locale, his original code outputs a currency symbol - determining that symbol is part of the locale functionality)